# Cordova alerts repeat on navigation

Tags: javascript, cordova, navigation, alert

I have trouble with repeating alerts in Cordova (phonegap), javascript looks like this:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
                'Something is amiss',  // message
                function(){},         // callback
                'DatabaseManager error processing SQL',            // title
                'Ok'                  // buttonName
            );
```

When i navigate to another page, like using back button, the alert is shown again. If i navigate further, the alerts are repeated x2 and so forth.

**Note:** It happens even when i try different navigation methods e.g.:

```
$.mobile.changePage("LogOn.html");
window.location.href = "LogOn.html";
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">back</a>
```

I'f found that scripts generally runs twice (alerts are just an example) when i navigate away from a page (but only on some occasions). I suspect that this happens because there's an error which i display in an alert, and the error cause the scripts run again in some magic way. Any ideas about what could be the cause?

**Bonus info:**
I use single page model (one page pr html file), load init and run my scripts from the html like this:

```
<script src="../js/PickMode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
            initPickMode(); //this method lives in PickMode.js
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to callback methods getting run again, which is especially a problem when callbacks are nested - which cause a complex debugging scenario. An example I found was a bug in jquery mobile popup (on android). I put a changePage navigation in the callback (on popup dismiss or something like that). The callback called the changePage like it should, but seemingliy there was a callback that caused the browser to return to where the popup occured.